# How do I keep the selected segment of UISegmentedControl inside UITableView when cell is reused?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol

My main problem is keeping the selected value of a UISegmentedControl when the cell that it is inside is reused.
When I scroll, the reused cell still has the same value for the segmented control.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)thisTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"yesNoCell";
testCell = [thisTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

// Configure the cell...
testCell.mainText.text = [ questionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[testCell.mainControl setFrame:CGRectMake(690, 22, 334, 40)];

return testCell;
}
```

Edit for clarification:
I want to keep the selection for each row. I may have, for example, 10 visible rows and 30 rows in all. When I select a segment in row 3, the row that shows up when "3" disappears has the same selected segment. I would like to make sure that the only rows with selected segments are those that the user actually changes.

Comment: Please elaborate your question. Do you want to keep the selection or change it?

Comment: I want to keep the selection for each row. I may have, for example, 10 visible rows and 30 rows in all. When I select a segment in row 3, the row that shows up when "3" disappears has the same selected segment. I would like to make sure that the only rows with selected segments are those that the user actually changes.

Comment: Will the contents of segmented control change or are they same for all cells?

Comment: Do it the same way you're updating `mainText`.

Comment: No the selected segment in the control will not change for all. I just want them to change for one and not for the reused version.

Comment: suppose you changed the segment value in index 3. when you scroll tableview then also that value should be there(segment value what you have changed) is this your requirement

Comment: No. If I were to change the segment value at index 3, that is the only value I would want to change. What is happening now is the value at index 3 is changing but it is also changing the value of some of the following cells because of the cell reuse function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your **model** for each row should have a property that keeps the selected segment, lets call it `selectedSegment`. When the user clicks on a segment you affect the value of the `selectedSegment` property for the instance of the object representing the affected row.

Then in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method, you update the UISegmentedControl's selected index with the value of the `selectedSegment` property.

Comment: Two tips which will aid in implementing Merlevede's correct answer: The value -1 for UISegmentedControl.selectedSegment equates to "nothing selected", and if you are subclassing UITableViewCell, the -prepareForReuse method can make sure things are reset nicely prior to each time the cell is recycled.

Comment: Thanks to all three of you. I will try these.

Answer (score 0):

Just keep selected indexes of segmented control in mutable array as NSNumber objects.

In `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)thisTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method set tag property of segmented control to indexPath.row and get selected value from array by indexPath.row

When segmented control changed selected index you need to replace selected index in array to new value(get the selected index value by tag value from array)

P.S
Initially you need to create indexes array with default values

Comment: I will try this as well.